# AngularUI Bootstrap Datepicker doesn't mark multiple days as "full"

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to feed Angular a list of dates and have it put an orange dot (status: 'full') on the datepicker for each date in the list.  For some reason, only the last date will be marked as full, even when I hard code each one.

```
// Should mark first 10 dates, but only marks the last date
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    dateInput = Date.parse(dates[$i]);
    $scope.events = [{
      date: dateInput,
      status: 'full'
    }];
  }

// This code will switch the dot to the date below
  $scope.events = [{
    date: Date.parse("Tuesday, September 22, 2015"),
    status: 'full'
  }];
```

Is there a way to set the status of multiple dates as "full"?  It seems kind of silly that it isn't just this easy because to my knowledge, full is just a style.

**Edit** this seems to be an issue with the format of the date.  When the date is formatted the way it is above, it is overwritten.  When it is formatted as

Wed Sep 23 2015 11:36:31 GMT-0500 (CDT)

more than one date can be set as status: 'full'.  I'm not sure what causes this, but I just need to figure out how to convert what I have an I'll be golden.

Comment: When you run this $scope.events just has an equals to it, meaning you're just overwriting $scope.events with each loop iteration. Is this supposed to be an object that you push to instead?

Comment: Yep, solved it right before I saw your comment.  I'm a bum :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$scope.events` just has an equals next to it.
You need to push the object up to it, for the correct status to be assigned.